# CSS and JS appear as plain text at top of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a page for the school where I work. The editor has an area where it will (supposedly) include in the header portion of the page. This is what is in that area:

```
<script src="uploaded/code/global_vars.js" type="text/javascript"language="javascript"></script>

<script src="uploaded/code/AccordionJS.js" type="javascript" language="javascript"></script>

<link href="uploaded/code/main.css?35" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="uploaded/code/AccordionCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="css">

<link href="uploaded/code/portal-flexible.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link href="uploaded/code/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->

<!-- JF #8347127 -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$j(document).ready(function () {
$j("#c_1272").find('.rss_page_link a').text('View this user on Pinterest');
});
</script>
```

I *Think* I have that portion right.

Yet when I save that layout and update the actual page, all of my CSS and JS are populated at the top of the page as plain text.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this? The menu I am trying to use was one I found through codepen and I have copied the sections from the CSS and JS fields respectively.

Thank you!

EDIT * Here is the HTML from the page,

```
<div class="container">
      <h1 class="heading-primary">CSS Responsive Animated Accordion</h1>
      <div class="accordion">
        <dl>
          <dt>
            <a href="#accordion1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion1" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">First Accordion heading</a>
          </dt>
          <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion1" aria-hidden="true">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eu interdum diam. Donec interdum porttitor risus non bibendum. Maecenas sollicitudin eros in quam imperdiet placerat. Cras justo purus, rhoncus nec lobortis ut, iaculis vel ipsum. Donec dignissim arcu nec elit faucibus condimentum. Donec facilisis consectetur enim sit amet varius. Pellentesque justo dui, sodales quis luctus a, iaculis eget mauris. </p>
            <p>Aliquam dapibus, ante quis fringilla feugiat, mauris risus condimentum massa, at elementum libero quam ac ligula. Pellentesque at rhoncus dolor. Duis porttitor nibh ut lobortis aliquam. Nullam eu dolor venenatis mauris placerat tristique eget id dolor. Quisque blandit adipiscing erat vitae dapibus. Nulla aliquam magna nec elementum tincidunt.</p>
          </dd>
          <dt>
            <a href="#accordion2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion2" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">
              Second Accordion heading</a>
          </dt>
          <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion2" aria-hidden="true">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eu interdum diam. Donec interdum porttitor risus non bibendum. Maecenas sollicitudin eros in quam imperdiet placerat. Cras justo purus, rhoncus nec lobortis ut, iaculis vel ipsum. Donec dignissim arcu nec elit faucibus condimentum. Donec facilisis consectetur enim sit amet varius. Pellentesque justo dui, sodales quis luctus a, iaculis eget mauris. </p>
            <p>Aliquam dapibus, ante quis fringilla feugiat, mauris risus condimentum massa, at elementum libero quam ac ligula. Pellentesque at rhoncus dolor. Duis porttitor nibh ut lobortis aliquam. Nullam eu dolor venenatis mauris placerat tristique eget id dolor. Quisque blandit adipiscing erat vitae dapibus. Nulla aliquam magna nec elementum tincidunt.</p>
          </dd>
          <dt>
            <a href="#accordion3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion3" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">
              Third Accordion heading
            </a>
          </dt>
          <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion3" aria-hidden="true">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eu interdum diam. Donec interdum porttitor risus non bibendum. Maecenas sollicitudin eros in quam imperdiet placerat. Cras justo purus, rhoncus nec lobortis ut, iaculis vel ipsum. Donec dignissim arcu nec elit faucibus condimentum. Donec facilisis consectetur enim sit amet varius. Pellentesque justo dui, sodales quis luctus a, iaculis eget mauris. </p>
            <p>Aliquam dapibus, ante quis fringilla feugiat, mauris risus condimentum massa, at elementum libero quam ac ligula. Pellentesque at rhoncus dolor. Duis porttitor nibh ut lobortis aliquam. Nullam eu dolor venenatis mauris placerat tristique eget id dolor. Quisque blandit adipiscing erat vitae dapibus. Nulla aliquam magna nec elementum tincidunt.</p>
          </dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please post the whole HTML header part, before the `<body>` tag

Comment: I copied the HTML from codepen as well. Do I need to add something here?

Comment: I can only add so many characters I guess here. Here is the beginning of the HTML on the page. <div class="container">
          <h1 class="heading-primary">CSS Responsive Animated Accordion</h1>
          <div class="accordion">
            <dl>
              <dt>
                <a href="#accordion1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion1" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">First Accordion heading</a>

Comment: Try replacing the first `<script` tag with this `<script src="uploaded/code/global_vars.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>`

Comment: Thank you for helping already. Changing that line doesn't appear to have made a difference.

Comment: <link href="uploaded/code/AccordionCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="css"> 
Here change the type to "text/css". Put all the link tags before the script tags. Also see that you have included all the script tags in correct order

Comment: There might be some errors with your JS files. Remove all the file references `.js` and `.css` and add one by one and see whether the error is still happening...

Comment: The problem remains... :( I don't know if it's okay to post links, but here is the CSS and JS code i'm trying to use https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3e77606bbc640a09d470

Comment: If you can't fit it here, create a gist or pastebin of your **entire** HTML file (from `<html>` to `</html>`). Chances are, you haven't closed a tag properly

Comment: Hi Phil. What I have above as HTML is all the HTML input I have given the page. The editor adds bannors ect but that is all the input I have on the page. I am brand new to all of this so it is likely a very amateur mistake. (and the github above contains the HTML CSS and JS)

Comment: You'll need to provide the entire code to beable to fix this

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you havent got a head in your document.... something similar to this

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
 <html>
   <head>
      <script src="uploaded/code/global_vars.js" type="text/javascript"language="javascript"></script>
      <script src="uploaded/code/AccordionJS.js" type="javascript" language="javascript"></script>
       <link href="uploaded/code/main.css?35" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        blahblahblah
   </head>
   <body>
```

And also that youre file is actually a .html file not just index.html.txt